# Que veulent vraiment dire « se passer », « se produire », « survenir » et « échoir » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Il y a plusieurs mots qui veulent dire la même chose et je n'ai jamais vraiment saisi comment ces mots s'emploient. Les mots de cette espèce que je vois le plus souvent sont *se passer* et *se produire*.

Le premier mot apparaît partout. Il me semble que l'on peut l'utiliser pour décrire un événement quelconque. Le deuxième mot paraît plus soutenu, et je dirais aussi que ce mot sert à décrire des choses qu'on voit moins souvent.
Le mot *survenir* apparaît moins souvent. C'est pourquoi je n'ai pas de connaissance de son emploi, une explication serait donc la bienvenue.

Je me rappelle aussi d'avoir une fois lu *échoir*. Je trouve que c'est un beau mot mais je n'ose pas l'utiliser à l'oral, car les mots qui se terminent par *choir* sont peu usités et mal compris.

Pourriez-vous me donner les différences et ajouter les mots qui appartiennent à la famille et sont usités et utiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« Se passer » dénote un évènement plus diffus dans le temps que « se produire ».

> L'histoire se passe à Paris.
>
> Un braquage s'est produit à 14h.

Survenir dénote un évènement soudain, inattendu.

> Lorsque nous étions prêts à partir, un orage survint.

Échoir dénote une échéance, une date à laquelle une opération financière doit être réglée.

> Le remboursement doit échoir le premier mars.

Échoir signifie aussi « être donné ».

> C'est à lui qu'échut l'héritage.

Answer (score 2):

On doit ajouter à cette liste « arriver ».

> Ça peut arriver. Ce sont des choses qui arrivent.

Au sujet des nuances de sens entre les variantes, elles sont relativement minimes et déjà évoquées dans la réponse de Méga Lag, c'est surtout les registres de langage qui sont assez différents :

- *Echoir* : soutenu hors usage professionnel, notamment comptabilité/finances
- *Survenir* : soutenu
- *Arriver* : courant
- *Se passer* : courant/familier